# How to read microsecond-precision mysql datetime fields with python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm using python's MySQLdb to fetch rows from a MySQL 5.6.7 db, that supports microsecond precision datetime columns. When I read a row with MySQLdb I get "None" for the time field. Is there are way to read such time fields with python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQLdb-1.2.4 (to be released within the next week) and the current release candidate has support for MySQL-5.5 and newer and should solve your problem. Please try 1.2.4c1 from PyPi (pip install MySQL-python)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, neither MySQLdb version 1.2.4b4 nor 1.2.4c1 have fixed the issue yet. It works, though, if you apply the patches of the mailinglist to the times.py file:

- to the function [DateTime_or_None](http://sourceforge.net/p/mysql-python/bugs/325/#6c55)
- to the functions [TimeDelta_or_None and Time_or_None](http://sourceforge.net/p/mysql-python/bugs/325/#3365)